# Entity Framework Exception in async code is not caught

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception

I have a service hosted on Azure, which will run in multiple instances simultaneously, it's async calls all the way up. In the deep of the chain, there is a method to save the data to database. I have the code to handle the exception when the multiple instances are trying to write the same data to database, but the exception never caught.

The Service hosted on Azure

```cs
 public async Task Start(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {

                 // Do something .... 
                await processedInventoryRepository.Commit(invenotyData).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

The Repository save data to database

```cs
public class Repository
    {
        public async  Task Commit(InventoryData data)
        {
            try
            {
                await SaveHardware(data.Hardware).ConfigureAwait(false); ;
                await SaveProduct(data.Product).ConfigureAwait(false); ;
                await SaveInstall(data.Installs).ConfigureAwait(false); ;
            }
            // Exception handle not handled here 
            catch (DbUpdateException ex)
            {
                var innerException = (SqlException)ex.InnerException;
                if (innerException != null && (innerException.Number == 2627 || innerException.Number == 2601))
                {
                  // log the error;
                }
            }
        }

        private async Task SaveInstall(DbContext _context, Install installs)
        {
            _context.Installs.Add(installs);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        private async Task SaveProduct(DbContext _context, Porduct product)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!_context.Products.Any(p => p.Id == product.Id))
                {
                    _context.Products.Add(product);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                }

            }
            // Exception not handled here 
            catch (DbUpdateException ex)
            {
                var innerException = (SqlException)ex.InnerException;
                if (innerException != null && (innerException.Number == 2627 || innerException.Number == 2601))
                {
                   // log the error
                }
            }
        }
```

There is nothing special in the data saving to the database, but worth to mention that Install has a foreign key of Product.

The exception happened in the SaveProduct Method, which is expected, as multiple instance are racing to add the same lookups. That's why the catch clause is placed there trying to ignore this error and let the execution carry on.  _context.Produts.Add(product) is OK, but exception is thrown when the SaveChanges is called. none of those catch works.

It's hard to get the stripped code to replicate the problem, I had same code in web api, and trigger it by using postman, it works as there is no exception. But in Azure, once there are multiple instances are running, the exceptions are happening all the time.

The exceptions are OK, but I just can't figure out how to handle them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you really getting `DbUpdateExceptions`? These are the only ones you handle in the code you have posted.

Comment: So maybe you get another Type of exception?

Comment: What is the exception? Paste it here, also 'The exception happened in the SaveProduct Method...', you do not have `SaveProduct` method in the sample code.

Comment: We would  also like to know if that _context is used on a single thread. so no Task.Run() anywhere?

Comment: @RosdiKasim - yeah, the alst piece of code is not in any method.

Comment: For starters, you're breaking the way EF is supposed to work by calling SaveChanges inside each method. Add all new items to the context and called SaveChangesAsync just once to commit all changes. SaveChangesAsync uses a transaction internally and performs all modifications in a single batch

Comment: What is this `try/catch` thingy below `SaveInstall`? Did i miss something?

Comment: As for your code, there may *not* be any exception if the ID is an auto-generated value. In that case, `Products.Any(p => p.Id == product.Id)` will return false in every case.

Comment: In general, ORMs like EF are a *higher level* abstraction compared to generic repositories. They were needed way back when we had to write the queries by hand. EF does the same things this repository is trying to do and more

Comment: Sorry all, messed up the code. Updated now, hope it's clearer.

@mm8 yes I am only "swallow" the DbUpdateException and only there is a duplicate key conflict. If anything else happens, that's unexpected, I still want to raise it.

Comment: @RosdiKasim, The unhandled exceptions are DbUpdateException indeed.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, sorry for the copy paste error, each method (saveProduct, SaveInstall) will have db.SaveChangesAsync(), so that db commit the  the changes in the end of each methods. and Id is not auto-genearted, it was assigned before it reaches DB

Comment: @nilsK, Hope it's clear now?